# DatabaseException after minifyEnabled true

Tags: exception, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, proguard

This entity working with Firebase RealmDataBase correcrly, but when i add

```
minifyEnabled true
```

in gradle for build, i got this ->

```
DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: sName
```

p.s. If I change the name of the fields that give me this exception, then these names will be saved on the server, I think the problem starts with annotations for the fields

Its my entity

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class Account(
@get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_NAME) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_NAME) var name: String,
@get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_SNAME) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_SNAME) var sName: String,
@get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_CITY) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_CITY) var city: String,
@get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_GYM) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_GYM) var gym: String,
@get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_WEIGHT) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_WEIGHT) var weight: String,
@get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_HEIGHT) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_HEIGHT) var height: String,
@get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_URI_PICTURE) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_URI_PICTURE) var imageUrl: String,
@Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude var followers: List<String> = emptyList(),
@Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude var subscribers: List<String> = emptyList(),
@Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude var countAchievements: List<String> = emptyList()
) : AccountListGrouper, Parcelable {

@Exclude
override fun getItemType() = TYPE_ACCOUNT

constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
    source.readString() ?: "",
    source.readString() ?: "",
    source.readString() ?: "",
    source.readString() ?: "",
    source.readString() ?: "",
    source.readString() ?: "",
    source.readString() ?: ""
)

@Exclude
override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    dest.writeString(name)
    dest.writeString(sName)
    dest.writeString(city)
    dest.writeString(gym)
    dest.writeString(weight)
    dest.writeString(height)
    dest.writeString(imageUrl)
}

constructor() : this("", "", "", "", "", "", "")

@Exclude
override fun describeContents() = 0

companion object {
    @JvmField
    val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Account> = object : Parcelable.Creator<Account> {
        override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): Account = Account(source)
        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Account?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
}
```

Its all that i try add to proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class com.voitenko.dev.training_booster.** { *; }
-keep class com.sdsmdg.harjot.** { *; }

#Firebase
-keepattributes Signature
-keepclassmembers class com.voitenko.dev.training_booster.models** { *;}
-keepnames class com.voitenko.dev.training_booster.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }


#_____________
# Needed for DNS resolution.  Present in OpenJDK, but not Android
-dontwarn javax.naming.**

# Don't warn about checkerframework
#
# Guava uses the checkerframework and the annotations
# can safely be ignored at runtime.
-dontwarn org.checkerframework.**

# Guava warnings:
-dontwarn java.lang.ClassValue
-dontwarn com.google.j2objc.annotations.Weak
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn javax.lang.model.element.Modifier

# Okhttp warnings.
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.google.j2objc.annotations.**
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem was add

`@Exclude`

for ALL! for all variables. I think this is necessary because during compilation of kotlin to Java, get () and set () are created for the public variable: In this case, Firebase does not know which option to use, either the public variable or the get and set methods
So my code now it

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class Account(
@Exclude @get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_NAME) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_NAME) var name: 
String = "",
@Exclude @get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_SNAME) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_SNAME) var sName: 
String = "",
@Exclude @get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_CITY) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_CITY) var city: 
String = "",
@Exclude @get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_GYM) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_GYM) var gym: 
String = "",
@Exclude @get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_WEIGHT) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_WEIGHT) var 
weight: String = "",
@Exclude @get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_HEIGHT) @set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_HEIGHT) var 
height: String = "",
@Exclude @get:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_URI_PICTURE) 
@set:PropertyName(ACCOUNT_URI_PICTURE) var imageUrl: String = "",
@Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude var followers: List<String> = emptyList(),
@Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude var subscribers: List<String> = emptyList(),
@Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude var countAchievements: List<String> = emptyList()
)
```

But i dont know why its worked correctly without minifyEnabled true ^_^